# запись значения в static const при инициализации программы на с

Tags: c, const

есть следующий псевдокод

```
#include<stdio.h>

....
static const int y;

int main
{...}

void myfunc1(...)
{}
int myfunc1(...)
{}
```

как записать в переменную `y` значение с помощью функции во время запуска программы? то есть проинициализировать её. каким должен быть синтаксис. когда функция должна вызываться? И есть ли способы так сделать?
Язык чистый с. Я плохо умею объяснять. Но хотелось бы узнать

1. Как проинициализировать во время исполнения программы данную
   переменную. Допустим пользователь ввёл число, на основании этого
   числа посчитался результат и записался в `static const int y` (именно
   `const`!!! именно глобальная переменная на уровне файла)
2. То же самое но во время компиляции к примеру так: `static int ret =
   myfunc1(&blabla, "blabla"); //gcc` так делать не дает, но
   использовать хочу именно так.

Требуется проинициализировать только 1 раз поскольку `const`. Но как?

Comment: Вопрос на засыпку :) - зачем вообще менять const-значение? Может, стоит подумать о том, как добиться результата без этого? Иначе вообще какой смысл в `const`?

Comment: тут скорее не менять а присвоить. В Java есть статический блок инициализации для этого. В С11 есть возможность сделать функцию constexp и присвоить, но мне лично кажется что если это можно сделать, то можно и просто присвоить константу сразу и не вызывать функцию (ну или вызвать отдельно где-то и записать значение).

Comment: Ну, всегда можно поиздеваться в духе `*(int*)&y =`, но что-то мне подсказывает, что так поступать не стоит...

Comment: @Harry очень большая вероятность что упадёт с повреждением стека, это не считая того что компилятор может тупо заинлайнить константу.

Comment: @Harry В данном случае `*(int*)&y =` это _Undefined behaviour_

Comment: Вот на `c++` вообще таких проблем нет :) А в сях надо именно значение времени компиляции подпихнуть для такой инициализации.

Comment: @StateItPrimitive А я что иносказательно сказал? :)

Comment: @Harry Я просто к тому, чтобы автор не стал использовать такое здесь)

Comment: переменная объявлена но не определена. Как её проиницализировать при запуске.

Comment: @user206991 Ваш вопрос-то мы поняли, просто считаем что в данном случае это невозможно (по крайней мере сколько-нибудь адекватными способами).

Comment: @StateItPrimitive в плюсах вроде есть такая возможность.

Comment: Но вы же сами указали на необходимость использования _"чистого c"_. Можем подождать пока этот пост посетит @avp и скажет наверняка.

Comment: В плюсах есть. Даже без `constexpr`. Например: `int gety()
{
    printf("gety\n");
    return 5;
}

const int y = gety();

void main()
{
    printf("y = %d\n",y);
}`

Comment: @Harry а можно чуть подробнее почему это работает? Или это особенности реализации конкретного компилятора?

Comment: @pavel В стандарте не скажу, я не настолько хорошо его знаю. Но эта штука давно уже работает. Вызывается такая функция до `main()`. Порядок вызова, естественно, не гарантируется. Думаю, что это было сделано в связи с тем, что при определении глобального объекта класса все равно должен вызываться его конструктор - до `main()` - так что все равно функциональность пришлось делать.

Comment: @Harry Стоп, но ведь автор хотел разнести _объявление_ и _определение_ константы, а тут по факту выйдет _определение_ в месте _объявления_.

Comment: @StateItPrimitive Ну, во-первых, это C++, я не даю это как решение, а отвечаю на вопрос о наличии такой возможности в C++... а во-вторых, автор хочет, мягко говоря, странного - чтоб и `const`, и не `const`. Такое и C++ не позволит...

Comment: такое только паскаль позволял из тех языков, с которыми я сталкивался)

Answer (score 1):

В этом вопросе вижу противоречие: вы объявляете глобальную переменную (UPD: не **static**) (что значит, она будет инициализирована до выполнения **main()**) и **const** (не меняет значения) и хотите поменять значение внутри **main()**. Не так?

Вижу два решения (по степени костыльности):

- define;
- pointer;

В первом - дефайнить выражение, во втором - нацелить указатель на нужное значение в вашей функции.

Но, всё же,  мне кажется, стоит лучше выяснить для себя, какое именно поведение нужно для этой переменной.

UPD: безусловно, вы правы, alexolut, не модификатор static делает ее живущей до конца работы приложения.

Comment: `static` говорит о том, что переменная не будет видна в других единицах трансляции. **Любые** глобальные переменные инициализируются до вызова `main`.

Answer (score 0):

Т.к. глобальная переменная `y` имеет модификатор `const` (т.е. должна быть инициализирована в месте определения) и при этом обладает `static storage duration`, то Стандарт `C11` по этому поводу говорит следующее (6.7.9/4):

> All the expressions in an initializer for an object that has static or
>   thread storage duration **shall be constant expressions** or string
>   literals.

При этом определение `constant expression` такое (6.6/2):

> A constant expression can be **evaluated during translation** rather than
>   runtime, and accordingly may be used in any place that a constant may
>   be.

Т.о. значение должно быть известно на момент трансляции кода.

**Получить его** в качестве результата **путём вызова функции** (которая по определению выполняется в рантайме) **невозможно**.

Comment: а в голом С стандарте нет constexp функций совсем никаких?

Comment: @pavel они в `c++` то появились только в 2011, а Вы хотите их в сях ... голых :)

Comment: а не подскажите существует ли вменяемая возможность инициализации массаива консант во время компиляции?

Comment: @pavel а в чем проблема? `const int y[] = {1, 2, 3};`

Comment: вы видимо не совсем поняли, пример прикладной задачи - посчитать простые числа первые там миллион например, через список это мягко говоря неудобно, нечитабельно и растаращивает исходник, можно это как-то положить в функцию которая при компиляции (не запуске) проинициализует массив.

Comment: @pavel только если сгенерить си код одной программой и подпихнуть его другой.

Comment: @pavel Знаете, а вам может подойти функция со статической переменной... Например, тот же массив простых чисел - при первом обращении к функции просчитывает таблицу, и функция возвращает значение, которое и есть по сути константное :)

Comment: @Harry оно всё равно будет вычислено в ран-тайме пусть и до вызова main. Мне на олимпиаду удобно бы было, там ограничение на размер исходника и на время, а так если грязные хаки типо https://bitbucket.org/jjeka/mathcpp/src или магия шаблонов, на шаблоны позволяют только простую функцию вычислить и у них уровень вложенности порядка 1000, а хотелось бы больше. Вот и интересуюсь может кто-то знает. А хаки пока напишешь времени много тратится.

Comment: @pavel И как это соотносится с тем, что для вычислений пользователь должен ввести число? Это же чистый ран-тайм...

Comment: @Harry без ввода числа, миллион константа приведена для примера и порядка.

Comment: @Harry статическая переменная в функции может быть инициализирована только константой времени компиляции.

Comment: @alexolut  Тут с кодом плохо, но, думаю, вы расшифруете :) Чем это поведение `f()` отличается от константы, инициализированной пользователем? `int f(int x)
{
    static int y = -1;
    if (y < 0) y = x;
    return y;
}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    printf("%d\n",f(2));
    printf("%d\n",f(5));
}
`